# Update values in a google sheet based on values from another google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, setvalue

I'm trying to update values in a table in googles sheet based on values in another sheet.  Help I don't know what I'm doing and nothing I've tried is working... this is some of  what I've tried so far...

```
function UpdatePickTScores(Player, GameDate, Goals, Assists, Hits, PIM, TotalScore, GameDateValue) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc…"); 
  var PicksT = ss.getSheetByName("PicksT");
  var sheet = PicksT; // SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var rowsView = 0; 

 for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { 
  var row = values[i]; 
  if (row[4] == GameDateValue && row[3] == Player)  {


  row[6] = Goals;
  row[7] = Assists;
  row[8] = PIM;
  row[9] = Hits;
  row[10] = TotalScore;

  Logger.log(i);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,6).setValue(Goals)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,7).setValue(Assists);  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,8).setValue(PIM);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,9).setValue(Hits);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,10).setValue(TotalScore);  


}
```

Comment: What about it is not working? Please give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved your similar issue by using the sheet's functions.
So for example I have a sheet that is populated by form's answers (we call it: "Sheet_A".
"Sheet_B" is a new different google sheet that I use to show some values, based on the answers received from the google form.
I solved inserting in "Sheet_B" the function IMPORTRANGE and combining it with other functions (e.g.: IF, COUNTA, FILTER, JOIN, etc..).
Sheet_B updates automatically on changing Sheet_A.